# How to grab unique rows from a nested table correctly?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table, called `A`, that looks like this:

```
|       mytimestamp       | col2 | col3 |
|=========================|======|======|
| 2019-11-27 14:30:00 UTC | xxxx | yyyy |
| ....................... | .... | .... |
| 2019-11-27 14:42:28 UTC | tttt | zzzz |
```

`col3` is part of a `REPEATED RECORD` called `cols`

I want to flatten the data with standardSQL and then grab only the unique combinations of 
`DATE(mytimestamp)`, `col2`, `col3`.

Below are 4 different versions of the queries that I ran and the numbers of returned different results:

**Version 1** (unnest)

```
SELECT
    DATE(mytimestamp) AS my_date
    ,col2
    ,c.col3 AS as un_col3
FROM
    my_dataset.A
    ,UNNEST(cols) AS c
-- Adding this will return different results.
-- GROUP BY
--     my_date
--     ,col2
--     ,un_col3
```

The version with the `GROUP BY` returned `4236104` results.
The version without the `GROUP BY` returned `1107740805` results.

**Version 2** (unnest + distinct)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(mytimestamp) AS my_date
    ,col2
    ,c.col3 AS as un_col3
FROM
    my_dataset.A
    ,UNNEST(cols) AS c
-- Adding this will return the same results.
-- GROUP BY
--     my_date
--     ,col2
--     ,un_col3
```

With or without `GROUP BY` it returns `875301` results.

**Version 3** (no unnest + distinct)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(mytimestamp) AS my_date
    ,col2
    ,c.col3 AS as un_col3
FROM
    my_dataset.A
    ,A.cols AS c


-- Adding this will return the same results.
--GROUP BY
--    my_date
--    ,col2
--    ,un_col3
```

With or without `GROUP BY` it returns `875301` results.

**Version 4** (no unnest + no distinct)

```
SELECT
    DATE(mytimestamp) AS my_date
    ,col2
    ,c.col3 AS as un_col3
FROM
    my_dataset.A
    ,A.cols AS c

-- Adding this will return different results.
--GROUP BY
--    my_date
--    ,col2
--    ,un_col3
```

The version with the `GROUP BY` returned `4236104` results.
The version without the `GROUP BY` returned `1107740805` results.

From the results and what I know, since `DISTINCT` applies to all columns I get the same results with or without having `GROUP BY`.

But why does Version 1 `with GROUP BY` give me different results that Version 2 or 3.

Which version is the correct/best one for what I want to do? I guess it's 2 or 3 because of the fewer returned rows, but why?

Thanks

Comment: is cols column just RECORD or REPEATED RECORD?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant it's a REPEATED RECORD. Will edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and produces correct result based on desired logic

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT DATE(mytimestamp) mydate, col2, col3
FROM `project.dataset.table`
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(cols)
```

As a test - if to apply to below oversimplified dummy data

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2019-11-27 14:30:00 UTC' mytimestamp, 'xxxx' col2, [STRUCT('yyyy' AS col3), STRUCT('zzzz')] cols UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-11-27 14:30:00 UTC', 'xxxx', [STRUCT('yyyy')] UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-11-27 14:42:28 UTC', 'tttt', [STRUCT('zzzz'), STRUCT('zzzz')] 
)
```

result will be

```
Row mydate      col2    col3     
1   2019-11-27  xxxx    yyyy     
2   2019-11-27  xxxx    zzzz     
3   2019-11-27  tttt    zzzz
```

Comment: does the left join without ON work in this case because you have applied DISTINCT? I just don't get since it doesn't know where to JOIN how do I not see duplicates. Even if I add more dates where one will have "xxxx" and the other won't have it, it still knows.

Comment: it works in cases when you join unnested fields, because it "kind of" joins with row from which that field is

Comment: @Lev, you might want to add the data example with more dates and columns to see if the query in this answer works for that case.

Comment: @rsantiago I did and it worked. I just don't know why "it "kind of" joins with row from which that field is" from what Mikhal mentioned.